# Microsoft Sync multiple scope with SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

Does SQL Server 2005 support multiple scope during synchronization? I'm using Microsoft Sync Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg294195%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), yes.

Answer (score 0):

if you're referring to synching multiple scopes at a time, the answer is no. you can only sync one scope at a time per synchronization session.

if you're referring to having multiple scopes defined, yes, you can define multiple scopes.